# Writing to a file from inside worker in spark local mode doesn't write?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For my application development in pyspark before running in a yarn cluster I want to test it in local mode. For this I need to write some data explicitly from inside the worker node, I think I can use hadoop rest api to do that for writing files into hdfs when running in cluster mode. But while running the code in local mode,how can I write to a file from inside the worker task?

For example:-

```
 sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("testing").setMaster("local[*]")
 sc= SparkContext(conf=sparkConf)

 rdd = sc.textFile("file://path to file")
 rdd.map(lambda x:x.split("\t")[0],1).reduce(func_to_reduce);

 def func_to_reduce(a,b):
    //how can i write value of a and b to a file from here
    return a+b;
```

For clarification: It works if I write to a file using open() method from the driver side code, but doesn't if I use the same thing to write to a file from inside the reduce function. Any direction or help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly are you attempting to write to a file?

Comment: @JoeC well i am comparing the two values and based on the analysis i need to write some new data into a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason why i posted this question was using os module to create directory and open() method to write to a file was not working from inside the reduceByKey() function. As i was running in the local mode, i assumed it should have access to my driver's local path and perform these functions as if i was running a normal python script. The reason why it was not is that i completely forgot the fact that reduceByKey is more like a transformation than an action because of which the code inside reduceByKey() was actually not running as per Spark's lazy evaluation design. Therefore, i called an action on that reference using collect(). Now it started the reduce functionality and is writing the files fine. Thanks for the help guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually call a save method, just as you called a load method via `textFile`. Something like `saveAsTextFile(path)`

Comment: well i am not trying to save my reduction results into a file. I am trying to explicitly write some data from inside the reduce function so that the file is written even before the job ends in spark. Hope that makes sense. I know it is not what spark has been designed for but i have to do that for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the `rdd.reduce(f)` soucre code

Spark call the python build-in function `reduce`  twice when using `rdd.reduce()`: one in worker node through `rdd.mapPartitions()` and another in driver node after `rdd.collect()`.

So you can not write data inside the `rdd.reduce` function

It seems that you want to save data on worker node's local path ?

Comment: no i want to save the data in driver node's local path. Anyway since i am running the job in local mode, either way it is gonna be the same file system ? Does that make it clear ?